# SQLite query is too slow

Tags: sqlite

I have the following query that is very slow. Is there another way of doing it to improve the search speed?

```sql
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         c.id AS VERSEid01,
         c.BookID,
         c.Word
  FROM FullConcordance c
  WHERE c.BookID = \(bookID) AND c.Word = '\(myString)'
 ),
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         b.Book,
         v.id AS VERSEid02,
         v.BookID,
         v.Chapter,
         v.Verse,
         v.VerseText
  FROM VersesPlain v
  JOIN Books b ON v.BookID = b.id
  WHERE v.BookID = \(bookID)
 )
```

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "FullConcordance" (
  "Word" text,
  "BookID" integer,
  "id" integer
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "VersesPlain" (
  "id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
  "BookID" integer,
  "Chapter" integer,
  "Verse" integer,
  "VerseText" text
);
```

Comment: Please, show also the schemata of the tables so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've included the tables schemata in my question.

Comment: You've not included the schema for Books, and your SQL query is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could likely improve the performance somewhat by utilising indexes, which you appear to not be using.

You could also likely better understand what indexes by referring to:-

- https://sqlite.org/queryplanner.html,
- https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html, and
- https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html

  - and also links within the above.

As an example as the bookid column in both the fullconcordance table and the versesplain table are referrred to in the WHERE clause and the JOIN clause then it could well improve efficiency to have an index on both.

This can be borne out, in theory, by utilising **`EXPLAIN`**

- `EXPLAIN` followed by the SELECT SQL, or probably initially
- `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` (rather than just EXPLAIN)

Perhaps consider the following **demonstration** that does both prior to and after adding some indexes.

- Note that although indexes may well improve the efficiency of SELECTs, they will have some overheads as the indexes have to be maintained.

The demonstration uses the following:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fullconcordance;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS versesplain;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;

/* Create the tables according to the information available from the question */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FullConcordance (
  Word text,
  BookID integer,
  id integer
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS VersesPlain (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY,
  BookID integer,
  Chapter integer,
  Verse integer,
  VerseText text
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    book text
);

/* Do the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN WITHOUT ADDITIONAL INDEXES */
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         c.id AS VERSEid01,
         c.BookID,
         c.Word
  FROM FullConcordance c
  WHERE c.BookID = bookID AND c.Word = '\(myString)'
 ),
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         b.Book,
         v.id AS VERSEid02,
         v.BookID,
         v.Chapter,
         v.Verse,
         v.VerseText
  FROM VersesPlain v
  JOIN Books b ON v.BookID = b.id
  WHERE v.BookID = bookID
 );
 EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         c.id AS VERSEid01,
         c.BookID,
         c.Word
  FROM FullConcordance c
  WHERE c.BookID = bookID AND c.Word = '\(myString)'
 ),
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         b.Book,
         v.id AS VERSEid02,
         v.BookID,
         v.Chapter,
         v.Verse,
         v.VerseText
  FROM VersesPlain v
  JOIN Books b ON v.BookID = b.id
  WHERE v.BookID = bookID
 );
 /* ADD some indexes that may be useful*/
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_versesplain_bookid;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_versesplain_bookid ON versesplain (bookid);
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_fullconcordance_bookid;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_fullconcordance_bookid ON fullconcordance (bookid);
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS idx_fullconcordance_word;
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_fullconcordance_word ON fullconcordance (word);

/* Now do the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN WITH THE INDEXES */ 
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         c.id AS VERSEid01,
         c.BookID,
         c.Word
  FROM FullConcordance c
  WHERE c.BookID = bookID AND c.Word = '\(myString)'
 ),
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         b.Book,
         v.id AS VERSEid02,
         v.BookID,
         v.Chapter,
         v.Verse,
         v.VerseText
  FROM VersesPlain v
  JOIN Books b ON v.BookID = b.id
  WHERE v.BookID = bookID
 );
EXPLAIN 
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         c.id AS VERSEid01,
         c.BookID,
         c.Word
  FROM FullConcordance c
  WHERE c.BookID = bookID AND c.Word = '\(myString)'
 ),
 (SELECT DISTINCT
         b.Book,
         v.id AS VERSEid02,
         v.BookID,
         v.Chapter,
         v.Verse,
         v.VerseText
  FROM VersesPlain v
  JOIN Books b ON v.BookID = b.id
  WHERE v.BookID = bookID
);
 
/* Clean Up The Demo Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS fullconcordance;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS versesplain;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;
```

It produces 4 outputs, an `EXAPLIN QUERY PLAN` and an `EXPLAIN` for before and after the indexes.

The `EXPLAIN` is more in-depth so the following is in regard to just the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN`'s

Before the indexes (result 1):-

[image]

After (result 3) :-

[image]

The highlighted detail showing that the indexes have come into play as opposed to a FULL TABLE SCAN. The first, shows that rather then searching through every row in the fullconcordance table instead the index on the **word** column is used to locate the word, likewise for the WHERE clause for the bookid on the versesplain table.

- note that the bookid has been assumed to be the PRIMARY KEY for the books table (and hence that index is taken into consideration).
  ***this answer is not intended to be the/an actual fix but rather an indication of the route that may fix the issue.***
- *actually ascertaining the benefits would involve loading the tables with data and probably a significant amount of data.*